Soft-Science-Fiction: How could i make the radiation of this star be less lethal to life?
Im working on a project which is based on several worlds orbiting around a white star like Sirius.
Sure life won't form there like we know it on earth because these stars are too short lived and radiate a lot in the UV spectrum. But maybe colonists using high-tech could settle there, shield themselves from the deadly UV radiation, form an atmosphere and ultimately oceans and ecosystems would evolve.
Im assuming all the planets in the habitable zone have a magnetic field.
Question: What measures could they take to shield the planets from the intense radiation, if they had Any technology to their disposal?

Your question is ill posed. The answer is obviously the patented "technology that shields the planet from intense UV radiation", technology we don't have yet, but such an answer won't move you an inch from where you are now.

I am not sure that I understand why would the colonists attempt to colonize a planet orbiting a hostile star, instead of, you know, chose a more friendly star?

Okay but maybe we could formulate a hypothetical technology, that would Do the job

Like how could you neutralize waves? By other waves. How can you shield yourself from particles?  Maybe get certain gasses/elements into the atmosphere who can deflect those particles?

No sci fi tech required if you don't have a need to spend thousands of years on a hugely wasteful vanity project like terraforming. A dome will do.

Okay so kind of a reflective glass or metal alloy will do the trick?

In form of a dome-like construction?

Electromagnetic field shielding:
The world is surrounded by a more intense electro-magnetic field, warding of particles. Even more effective.. the world has a smaller doppelgaenger (maybe even artificial)- circling on a more sunward synchronized orbit, producing a strong magnetic field, that diverts the solar winds.
Water as shield:
Water makes for a lousy shield for particles, but having enough of it, it can soak up some damage. That is, as long as its there. Huge clouds or ice rings in high orbit, taking up the damage.
Geography as shield:
Without those shields, there remain, mountains and mirrors. Basically you hope for an "eye" region of a tidally locked planet and use the mountains as radiation shielding, while having foilsails on zeppelins to mirror the good light back to you. You still have huge problems, with loads of ozone and isotope rich rain etc. but you don't get toasted on the first day.

Why would an electromagnetic field help against ultraviolet rays?

Oh, against UV it does not help at all. It helps with charged particles. UV is easy, as it produces its own counter measure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_layer

So we could have a combination of an ozone layer, particles and a magnetic field. In my scenario the world's already have such a field from their inner core
